# Unwanted sign extension in Arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am trying to achieve logical right shift in Arduino(i.e. avoid sign extension), and after reading the Arduino BitShift guide (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Bitshift), it suggests that shifting unsigned variables to the right, wont cause sign extension:

> When you shift x right by y bits (x >> y), and the highest bit in x is
>   a 1, the behavior depends on the exact data type of x. If x is of type
>   int, the highest bit is the sign bit, determining whether x is
>   negative or not, as we have discussed above. In that case, the sign
>   bit is copied into lower bits, for esoteric historical reasons:
>
> ```
> int x = -16;     // binary: 1111111111110000
> int y = x >> 3;  // binary: 1111111111111110 This behavior, called sign extension, is often not the behavior you want. Instead, you may
> ```
>
> wish zeros to be shifted in from the left. It turns out that the right
>   shift rules are different for unsigned int expressions, so you can use
>   a typecast to suppress ones being copied from the left.

In my tests, it doesn't work like that:

```
Serial.print( ((uint32_t)(1<<15)) >> 15, BIN);
```

Prints:

> 11111111111111111

Which means, there's sign extension going on.
I've also tried the suggested example from there, with the same results.

Am I doing something wrong?
Also Is it possible to do a shift and force the operation to be logical instead of arithmetic?

Comment: You can do away with the cast if you use unsigned integers to begin with, as in `(1u << 15) >> 15`.

Comment: `>>` over negative values is implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude even if I do that, sign extension still happens, 15 is not negative though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I think you left out some key information: it looks like you must be using an Arduino board with a 16-bit `int` type (e.g., Arduino Uno).

The problem here is how integer promotion works in C and C++. When you cast a 16-bit signed integer literal, `1<<15`, to a 32-bit unsigned integer literal, it will take the following steps:

1. You're casting from 16-bit up to 32-bit, so it will first extend your existing literal to 32-bits. Since it's a signed literal, it's first sign-extended to a 32-bit signed value.
2. Now that the operand have the same bit-width as the desired type, the compiler casts it to a 32-bit unsigned integer type.

I don't have a 16-bit machine sitting around to test this on, but I can duplicate the same behavior on my 64-bit laptop with this test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    printf("%" PRIx64 "\n", ((uint64_t)(1 << 31)));
    // prints ffffffff80000000
    printf("%" PRIx64 "\n", ((uint64_t)(1 << 31)) >> 31);
    // prints 1ffffffff
    return 0;
}
```

So you can see in this program, it's not the `>>` operation that's doing the unwanted sign extension, but rather the cast from a 32-bit signed integer to a 64-bit unsigned integer, because the cast actually acts like this:

`int32_t` → `int64_t` → `uint64_t`

If you want to avoid the extra sign extensions, you should either start with an unsigned literal (as Some programmer dude suggested in his comment), or make a cast to the same-width unsigned type. Any of these should work:

```
Serial.print( ((uint32_t)(1u<<15)) >> 15, BIN);
Serial.print( ((uint16_t)(1<<15)) >> 15, BIN);
Serial.print( ((uint32_t)(uint16_t)(1<<15)) >> 15, BIN);
```